# C# - Limit bandwidth of any process

Tags: c#, process, bandwidth

there are some processes on my machine that consume my entire bandwidth and I just can't use the internet anymore while they're active.

Is there a way to limit their bandwidth using C#?

I've managed to find the processes using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(id)`, but I can't seem to find any good option....

Comment: I don't think that's something you really have control over. Windows only really cares that the computer is responsive which is why you get Thread Priorities, CPU affinities, memory priorities, I/O priorities. I've never seen anything to specifically throttle a single process. Perhaps a proxy, but that's still all and not one.

Comment: The functionality you're requesting is much more low-level than anything that .NET exposes by default. You should look into bandwidth-limiting software - I used to use an application for this in a darker time of shared connections and limited throughput. Wasn't freeware, though.